# UWP App, Crash when data has "-" (minus) sign

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

my UWP App (.NET core 2.2) based start to crash when I add a combobox in ListView. It was working fine otherwise. But it crash is specific case. Let me tell that case.

I have a POC ordering system, a standard product and ordering part. So I create ordering screen that Bind a Product Code in Dropdown under listview. When User add new product row to order listview repeat it's data template. For new order this works, but when I try to load screen from selected order it crash on XAML parsing/binding. (Codebehind code fine through debugger).

After days of debugging, I finally got it working by removing "-" from product code. Now, the same list bind fine if database is not loading the screen yet binding the Product list in Listview, but it crash when I bind same list and select it based on db.

I try to debug the `IEqualable<>` Equal function to see if that is crashing but it never reach there.

Does anyone has any idea why it might be crashing. Visual Studio is unable to capture the exception or anything. I just got `Access Voilation` Error in Windows Event Log. nothing else it just crash.

Edit

```
<ListView Name="GridItems" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProName}" Width="200" Padding="2,5,2,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>

                <ComboBox x:Name="ProductSelection" MinWidth="150"  SelectionChanged="ProductSelection_SelectionChanged" 
                          IsTextSearchEnabled="False" Padding="5" Margin="5,10,5,0" IsEditable="False"                                                                           
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ListProducts}" SelectedValue="{Binding ProCode, Mode=TwoWay}" />            
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is XAML code, from backend in constructor we bind `ListProducts` with `List<string>` that contain the data from database with `-` in them.

When we run the code in "Add" mode it bind fine don't crash (when `SelectedValue=""` but then we have something in `SelectedValue="d-ddd"` then it crash.

The strange thing is same database code bind for product management with same code and it works there. I try to create error in separate standalone but could not get it produce there either.

in Event Viewer we get this entry (stripped from personal/app info)

```
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.22000.493, time stamp: 0x632525e9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001c8252
Faulting process ID: 0x7b7c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d820027aa4737d
```

it is not possible to debug as debugger do not get attach [even though we enable Win32 exception all cases in Debug mode for application], and try to bind it separately as well.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that could reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I make edit above if that helps

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample data model that you used for the listview item?

Comment: I made a simple data model to run your code. One thing I want to confirm is when does this issue happen? When you are compiling the code? Or when you are adding new rows to the listview? Or when you are selecting items of the combobox? It will be better if you could list the steps to reproduce it